# Get product id from value id

Tags: magento-1.7, product, configurable-product

I want to get product id from value id in configurable product detail page. I get product id easily from `catalog_product_entity` table but it gives me main configurable product id. But I want to know each associated product id from each associated product `value_id`. Currently I know that value id is coming from

```
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
```

[image]

Media.phtml

```
        <?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
            <?php //Skip, if no image
                if ($_image->getFile() == NULL)
                    continue; ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $zoomHelper->createImgUrl($this, $_product, $bigImageWidth, $bigImageHeight, 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>" class="cloud-zoom-gallery lightbox-group" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()); ?>"
                    rel="useZoom:'zoom1', smallImage: '<?php echo $zoomHelper->createImgUrl($this, $_product, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>'" <?php echo isset($cjm_colorselector_base[$_image->getId()])?'id="option_'.$cjm_colorselector_base[$_image->getId()].'"':''?>>

                    <img src="<?php echo $zoomHelper->createImgUrl($this, $_product, $thumbImgWidth, $thumbImgHeight, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile()); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()); ?>"/>

                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

here `$_image` object i get value id and i am using cloud zoom extension.
Any help Will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can you please describe your question. Where you will not get product id? I don't think there is a way to get product id from value_id instead of run raw query. You can look into this link for more details about simple query  http://blog.magecracker.com/how-to-write-simple-query-in-magento/

Comment: i know that how to execute query ..i want product id in configurable product detail page

Comment: can you please paste the code here to get all value_id of associated products?

Comment: its media.phtml,,i got value id from $_image object

Comment: can you please post here your media.phtml file content, In media.phtml you already get product Id using $_product = $this->getProduct(); "$_product->getId()", and I guess all $_image will show getGalleryImages of that particular product only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an `entity_id` from the same table.

Comment: but it gives entity_id of configurable product id.not my associated product entity_id

Comment: @KeyurShah. This means you are querying the wrong value_id.

Comment: @Marius i gives correct value_id but i am talking about configurable product detail page where i get different value_id of associated product id

Comment: Is the image belongs to associated product or configurable?

Comment: @Tim associated product image

Comment: then it should be `entity_id`.